# connecting to ms sql 2005 from java

Tags: java, sql-server

Can somebody help me connect to mssql 2005 with java.
Can somebody post me the link or sth to find jar and the url format.
What about jtds, what is the difference with microsoft? Which one to use better?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This shows an example of how to do it:

http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/jdbc/how-to-connect-microsoft-sql-server-using-jdbc.html

And here's the jDTS

http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html